# Elements Not Centering

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am making a website for a client of mine, but I have a problem.
I want 3 buttons with text pop up but they won't center.
When I checked the inspector I could see a weird margin right while I have not done this myself.

Thank you for all the replies, but sadly non of them worked. I think it has something to do with something else on my website.

It might be this:
[Photo Problem 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayXf5.png)

If you want code of a specific section, just say it I do not know what not to and what to put in here in terms of code.

```
#Buttons
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    }
    
.Button
{
    margin-right: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: white;
 }
    


<div id="Buttons">
   <div class="Button"></div>
   <div class="Button"></div>
   <div class="Button"></div>
</div>
```

[Photo of the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr2XK.png)

[Margin of the buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzYJt.png)

Comment: btw if you're creating buttons I suggest using the `<button>` element, as that's what it's there for. You'll get automatic accessibility with them as well!

Comment: Isn't the margin right part of the css for `.Button` ? If you change that to simply margin it should adjust things to the center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center the flex items, apply `justify-content: center` to the container.

And to set the margin of the last button to 0, add this rule:

```
.Button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Edit/note:  I made the buttons smaller for the snippet below to not extend the width of the snippet window.

```css
#Buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  background: blue;
}

.Button {
  margin-right: 50px;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
  background-color: white;
}

.Button:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Buttons">
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
  <div class="Button"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin` to `auto`.

```
.Button {
  margin: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Code sandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/html-code-editor-forked-f17y2?file=/style.css

Comment: @Jan-Jaap Bol, check this out!!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the 50px right margin in `.Button` and used `gap` in `#Buttons` to set the "minimum gutter" spacing of the elements:

```css
#Buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 1em;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.Button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="Buttons">
  <div class="Button">A</div>
  <div class="Button">B</div>
  <div class="Button">C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had the button centered, then upon reopening, buttons left aligned even though I did not change anything. the display:flex; keywords fixed the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).